# How can i get left clicking on my mouse to work again

Tags: 12.04

Ok so far i have been using Ubuntu 12.04 without any problem, but one the mouse clicker just don't work when i select something. Now it works when i am opening up a program, but to lets say i want to open up the file manager. I got to right click then select open then hit enter to open it and that goes for any thing else i want to open, what i am asking is how can i restore its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev
```

Restart and test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me.  Brought up command prompt. Typed in code.
Logged out (with the still working right click) and logged back in.
All good